# Unable to get <asp:HiddenField> value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am assigning the value to hidden field and I want to access that value in the JavaScript.

**My declarative part is:**

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="chkImages" runat="server" />
<div id="main" runat="server" style="display:none;"></div>
<a id="NewsTitle" runat="server" class="specialNews-label"></a>
```

**My JavaScript code is:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "#bxsliderid" ).parent().css( "display", "block" );
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        controls:false,
        pager:false,
        auto:true,
        speed: 9000,   
        easing: 'linear', 
        mode: 'fade',
        pause: 5000,
    });

    if(document.getElementById('<%= chkImages.ClientId%>').value == "1") {
        $( ".specialNews-label" ).css( "display", "block" );
    }
});
```

I opened the page and see in Firebug that the hidden field is rendered but I am not getting the value of it, while debugging the JavaScript I am getting error like: `Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference`

What am I missing?

Comment: check hidden field id is same as pass in javascript

Comment: can you post render javascript and html hidden field code?

Comment: Ok sir, here is the code which is rendered: `<input name="ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_5df4804c_7fc5_4955_aa12_c307c78f94e3$chkImages" id="ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_5df4804c_7fc5_4955_aa12_c307c78f94e3_chkImages" type="hidden" value="1"/>`

Comment: where is your javascript code written....on top of the page or bottom????

Comment: The JavaScript is in another file which is I am loading to the page.

Comment: and javascript render code

Comment: declare the hidden field as `<asp:HiddenField ID="chkImages" runat="server" Value="" />`

Comment: Which code do you want to know about sir? @rajeshkakawat

Comment: this one document.getElementById('<%= chkImages.ClientId%>').value

Comment: On the execution of that statement I am getting error `Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference` @rajeshkakawat

Comment: @MohemmadK check my answer what i am trying to say

Comment: Check out my answer and this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zW3fj/ It works.

Comment: Have you included jQuery?

Comment: @MohemmadK try my answer it is working with your server side HiddenField control.

Comment: OK sir, I am trying it..@BhaveshKachhadiya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You not need to change any thing in your HTML code you just change your javascript as follow:

In your Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "#bxsliderid" ).parent().css( "display", "block" );
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        controls:false,
        pager:false,
        auto:true,
        speed: 9000,   
        easing: 'linear', 
        mode: 'fade',
        pause: 5000,
    });

    if($("input[type='hidden'][id$='chkImages']").val() == "1") {
        //alert('test');
        $( ".specialNews-label" ).css( "display", "block" );
    }
});
```

See Demo for your rendered HTML :

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BhaveshKachhadiya/54gkW/11/)

Answer (score 1):

please try below... It is working fine... It

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert($('#chkImages').val());
            if ($('#chkImages').val() == "1") {
                $("#NewsTitle").css('display', '');
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="chkImages" runat="server" Value="1" />
        <div id="main" runat="server" style="display: none;">
            Test
        </div>
        <a id="NewsTitle" runat="server" style="display: none" class="specialNews-label">AAAA</a>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

hey brother there is letter case problem

try this-----

ClientID instead of ClientId

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestApp.MyForm" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnField" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert($("#<%= hdnField.ClientID %>").val());
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.attr('value')` in your code instead of `.value`. Since you appear to be using jQuery, you can do this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('#chkImages').attr('value') == "1") {
        alert("Working...");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zW3fj/

Comment: Thank you for helping sir, but still I am getting an issue, can send you my code?

Comment: Have you included jQuery?

Comment: yes sir, jquery as well as JavaScript file is loaded from the page layout and I am able to see these files in firebug.

Comment: I tried something for experiment and I put one HTML hidden field control in the aspx page and gave static value = 1 and I got the expected result, now I have only problem with server side control that is I am not able to access using `document.getElementById()` method..

Comment: Look at the fiddle in the answer. And you are using getElementById() server side?

Answer (score 0):

check id is same in my case it is my_id

js

```
document.getElementById('my_id').value == "1"
```

html

```
<input name="image_name" id="my_id" type="hidden" value="1"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering sir, but I need to change the value programmatically of hidden field. How do I set the value of field in code?

Comment: yes I know but view your page source see your id is same in both js and html

Comment: I am talking about about changing the value in C#, not in JS sir.

Comment: but your value should be change on both side ie js and html